# jQuery/Javascript: scrollTop Value in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, scroll

maybe a few others already asked that but I couldn't find any answer to the problem …

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        // Only works in Firefox and I guess in Opera
        console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);

        // Only works in Chrome and Safari
        console.log(document.body.scrollTop);

    });
```

I need this scrollTop value to be correct in every browser!
What's the way to that?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery method `scrolTop()` it will work in all the browsers.

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```